# C bus error when trying to acces a pointer in a pointer list, which is a struct point to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, graph-theory

I get a bus error whenever I try the following to do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// The nodes that hold the data
typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
} Node;

// The list of the data
typedef struct list {
    Node* head; // start of list of data
    Node* tail; // end of list of data
} List;

// A vertex node, e.g. node 1. The list represents all the nodes (aka vertecies) that this vertex is connected to
typedef struct vertex {
    List *L; // all the connected nodes (called nodes but is actually the numbers this node is connected to)
} Vertex;

// the list of all the vertices, which in themselves contain which nodes they are connected to (using a linked list)
typedef struct list_of_vertices {
    Vertex** Lv;
} l_vertex;

// creats a list with init values of NULL, so we do not access garbage memory later on.
List* createL() {
    List* L = malloc(sizeof(List));
    L->head = NULL;
    L->tail = NULL;

    return L;
}

int main() {
    l_vertex* L = malloc(sizeof(l_vertex));
    L->Lv = malloc(sizeof(Vertex)*5); // 5 vertices in the list of vertex

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        L->Lv[i]->L = createL();
    }

    if(!L->Lv[0]->L->head) { // crash (bus error)
        printf("There was no init\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I do not get any compiler errors. What I am trying to do is have a list of Vertices, each vertex has a linked list with which vertex they are connected to. This means l_vertex -> list of vertices -> individual vertex -> list of connections -> individual connect.

How do I achieve this and why do I get "Bus error"? I know a bus error is, e.g., when you try to access un-allocated memory.

Comment: Which is the exact line of code that triggers the fault? Run your program in a debugger to get that info and to aid in debugging in general.

Comment: `createL` need to return `L`.

Comment: That should be have been caught by your compiler's warnings. Make sure to enable (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc/clang) and head them!

Comment: Also, `-fsanitize=address` is great for debugging these problems.

Comment: Make sure you compile and run the code yourself and **copy&paste** the exact code to your question. There are several compiler warnings and errors in your code. I fixed the compiler errors, see https://onlinegdb.com/H1vX4UBEO . When you run it in a debugger, e.g. onlinegdb, until the segmentation fault occurs, then you can check the variables. You try to access a `NULL` pointer at `L->Lv[i]->L = createL();`

Comment: @Bodo I edited the code to match the one I got on my virtual computer where the code was.

Comment: Your `L->Lv` is declared as if it points to an array of *pointers* to `Vertex`.  You allocate size as if it points to an array of `Vertex`es themselves, you never initialize the pointers it actually contains, and then you dereference them, hence crash.  I suspect you wanted `l_vertex.Lv` to be of type `Vertex *` instead of `Vertex **`.

Comment: The code doesn't even compile.  the `typedef struct list` definition doesn't end with a semi colon.  The `typedef struct vertex (` should be `typedef struct vertex {` and the `struct node *previous` inside Node doesn't have a semicolon and `if(!L->Lv[0]->head) {` should probably be `if(!L->Lv[0]->L->head) {` (maybe - it's hard to tell what you are trying to do).  This can't be the code that is crashing when you run it...

Comment: If you change all the things to make it compile and then change what @NateEldredge suggested, then this doesn't crash: https://onlinegdb.com/Sy-mnwSEd

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I have now changed it to match my original code, this is now a minimally reproducible example. Sorry for the delay and the confusion, I am typing this from a new computer that has a different keyboard and stuffs. Thanks for everyone's patience and helpful comments!

Comment: @NateEldredge Your comment more accurately describes how I did things first. I changed it to be of type `**` because I got the bus error. I still get the bus error both with and without the "extra" `*`.

Comment: Then please show us that version of the code.  I get no crashes or AddressSanitizer errors when I make that change (and of course change `->` to `.` accordingly in the rest of the code).  See https://godbolt.org/z/5TPE5Y56P.  Does your `Vertex *` version have the fixed return value for `createL()`?

Comment: Ok, so the code now compiles but `list_of_vertices` still has `Vertex** Lv;` so the answer below actually fixes your problem: https://onlinegdb.com/r1nfZOSEO

Comment: be careful of statements like: !L->Lv[0]->L->head, it can fail if L is null, or if L->Lv is null or if L->lv[0] is null or if L->Lv[0]->L is null. If you are using checking you should check each of these in order, otherwise you can crash while checking.

Comment: @Dmitry I am fully aware of this but when I have check directly after creating a linked list inside a list of vertexes I get bus error because there is no "head" in the linked lists inside the singular vertex of the list of vertices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the `Lv` member of `l_vertex` to be a pointer-to-pointer to `Vertex`:

```
typedef struct list_of_vertices {
    Vertex** Lv;
} l_vertex;
```

This means that `Lv` can contain an array of pointers to `Vertex`.  But then here:

```
L->Lv = malloc(sizeof(Vertex)*5);
```

You allocate space for 5 instances of `Vertex` instead of 5 instances of `Vertex`, so you're not allocating the right amount of space.  Then when you do this:

```
L->Lv[i]->L = createL();
```

The pointer `L->Lv[i]` has not been initialized, so attempting to dereference it triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What you actually want in `l_vertex` is to hold an array of `Vertex`, so change it to:

```
typedef struct list_of_vertices {
    Vertex *Lv;
} l_vertex;
```

This subsequently makes the allocation correct.  Then you would access a `Vertex` like this:

```
L->Lv[i].L = createL();
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and got a bit further. Now I get bus error when I try to access the head of the list. If I do something like `L->Lv[0].L->head` then I get a bus error, because there is no "head" inside the list... I know there is a list because I did a check `if(L->Lv[0].L) {printf("Yes!\n");}` and it works.

Comment: @heyo Well yes, because `L->Lv[0].L->head` is NULL, so although you can check if it is NULL, attempting to dereference it (i.e. `L->Lv[0].L->head->next`) would be invalid.